# Issue with FadeOut effect not working in CSS animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a container element that I want to appear with a FadeIn effect using CSS animation. The code I currently have successfully applies the FadeIn effect, but I'm facing difficulty in getting the FadeOut effect to work. Here's the CSS code I'm using:

```
span.select2-container.select2-container--default.select2-container {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn 0.5s ease-in forwards;
  z-index: 1000 !important;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

span.select2-container.select2-container--default.select2-container.fadeOut {
  animation: fadeOut 0.5s ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

I expected the container to fade out gradually when I apply the fadeOut class, but instead, it immediately disappears without any animation.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and achieve the desired fade-out effect.

Comment: Hi do you apply the styles? With Javascript?